# How to fix this sonarqube blocker without affecting to the logic

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarcloud

Could you please look at below image and please let me know the solution for this. I have tried to write a try-with-reources for Statement and Resultset but inside try block what should I write

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWIz0.png)

Comment: Sonarlint shows that I have to include Resultset also so if I include result set inside trywith resources what should I write in the try block

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. Don't use comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, normally it should solve your problem

```
synchronized(this) {
  try (Connection sqlConnection= DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
     PreparedStatement ps = con.createStatement(q)) {
  
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while(rs.next()) {
          return result;
        }
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Let me know if it work for you

Comment: it should be synchronized

Comment: i just update my answer for you!